# Access methods or property from another class without calling ViewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, class, methods, properties

Typically, I would call another class method like this:
MyClass *class = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[class myMethod];

But the problem is that, it will call the ViewDidLoad. That is a problem for me.

Is there any way to access a property in another method or call a class in another method without calling the ViewDidLoad?

Thanks!

**Edit1**: So are you are saying that if I do this it will not call my VDL?:

```
MyClassB *classB = [[[MyClassB alloc] init] autorelease];
[classB.pauseButton setHidden:NO];
```

Also how about when I call a method will that trigger the ViewDidLoad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure;  refactor `myMethod` to *not* call `viewDidLoad`.

That is, if you call method `a` and method `a` calls `b`, but you don't want to call `b`, then you need to modify the implementation of `a` to sometimes not call `b`.  Either by modifying `a` or creating a new method `c` on the class containing `a` that doesn't call `b`.

If the problem is that you are calling a method in the system frameworks and it is calling `viewDidLoad` when you don't want, then the answer is that you really can't do what you think you want to do.  But that is just a symptom;  the real answer is that your app's architecture needs to be revisited to better fit with the system's frameworks.

---

> Edit1: So are you are saying that if I do this it will not call my
>   VDL?:

```
MyClassB *classB = [[[MyClassB alloc] init] autorelease];
```

That is creating a new instance of `MyClassB`.  If there is already an instance being displayed on screen, then you most likely do not need a new instance and, yes, that is the reason why `viewDidLoad` is being called.

Either create an instance variable that can point to the already existing instance of `classB` or otherwise have a means of grabbing that instance;  hang it off the app delegate or something.

Overall, it sounds like you are confused about what it means to instantiate an object vs. simply referring to one and how all that fits into the UIKit model of app creation.   It is a bit tricky until you get the hang of it.   Study some of the many examples that show how to use view controllers as they will likely have solved a similar problem.

Comment: Well pretty much I have a button in lets say Class A. Currently the button is showing in Class B. I want to be able to hide the button from Class A until I want to. Is there a way to do that without calling the View Did Load?

Comment: I'm not sure why hiding/showing the button would cause `viewDidLoad` to be called unless you are actually loading the view.  But if the button is already showing and viewDidLoad is called, are you sure you aren't creating a new instance of B, loading it, then hiding *that* button?

Answer (score 0):

You could create the view controller once and save it in an instance variable, then use the instance variable to call the method or access properties.

```
eg.
if(self.myClass==nil)
  self.myClass =  [[MyClass alloc] init];

[self.myClass doStuff];
[self.myClass.pauseButton setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: So in this code, I create an ivar and properties for my other class and the VDL never gets called with this code?